# validating text field value with numeric with two decimal only in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I want to check my form field's value whether it's numeric with two decimal and do the validation accordingly. It should accept numeric with two decimals ex: 2.33 else it should throw error like 2.987 it should not accept more than two decimal.  Can anyone help me with this?

I have tried following:

```
<cfif NOT isValid(#NumberFormat( 7.4, ",.00" )#, dataValue)>
```

Comment: i already tried  **<cfif NOT isValid(#NumberFormat( 7.4, ",.00" )#, dataValue)>**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080671/limit-cfinput-to-valid-currency-values is this helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are a nice way to validate. Have a look at which option you could use here:

```
<cfif not reFind("^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$", dataValue)>
    <cfthrow type="IllegalArgumentException" message="You may input a decimal value with two decimal places only!">
</cfif>
```

`^` = value has to start with the upcoming pattern
`[0-9]+` = match digits from 0 to 9, one digit or more
`\.` = a dot (literally), the backslash is an escape symbol since `.` has a different effect
`[0-9]{2}` = match digits from 0 to 9, exactly two digits
`$` = value has to end with the previous pattern

---

If you want to accept dot and comma as decimal separator, you can change `\.` to `[,.]`.
If you want to accept one or two decimal spaces, you can change `[0-9]{2}` to `[0-9]{1,2}`.

If you don't require decimal places at all, but when they are present, they have to have two decimal places:

```
<cfif not reFind("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$", dataValue)>
    <cfthrow type="IllegalArgumentException" message="You may input a decimal value without decimal places or with exactly two decimal places only!">
</cfif>
```

`(\.[0-9]{2})?` = the parenthesis group the pattern and the question mark marks it as "may match once" or "may not match at all".

Note: `[0-9]` is equivalent to `\d`. I just prefer to actually see the digits.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like using `cfinput` but in the interest of time:

```
<cfinput type="text" name="name" mask="9.99"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isValid()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/isvalid.html) along with a regular expression to validate this:

```
<cfset input = "7.44">
<cfif isValid( "regex", input, "^\d+\.\d{2}$" )>
    <!--- Valid input handler --->

<cfelse>
    <!--- Invalid input handler --->

</cfif>
```

Here is a [`GIST`](https://trycf.com/gist/8e165bf3b4697236b23b0de605150b17/acf11?theme=monokai).

**Note:-** Not related to your question but you don't need additional hash in the code that you have tried. You can check more [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069165/4362001).